# Case-insensitive text list sorting

Tags: elisp

There is a list of "спсВыбора":

`("ФайлыКаталоги" "Клиент Проверка Существования Каталога" "Клиент Проверка Существование Файла" "СтандартныеСтруктурыМодуля" "стндОбрОтв" "элКлючаОтветУспехОбрОтв" "элКлючаОтветОшибкаОбрОтв" "элКлючаОтветПроцедура" "элКлючаОтветМодуль" "стндОтчОтв")`

To sort, use the command:

`(setq спсВыбора (sort спсВыбора (lambda (a b) (string> a b))))`

As a result, the list of "спсВыбора":

`("элКлючаОтветУспехОбрОтв" "элКлючаОтветПроцедура" "элКлючаОтветОшибкаОбрОтв" "элКлючаОтветМодуль" "стндОтчОтв" "стндОбрОтв" "ФайлыКаталоги" "СтандартныеСтруктурыМодуля" "Клиент Проверка Существования Каталога" "Клиент Проверка Существование Файла")`

Sorting takes into account the separate order of lower and upper case letters. Tell me how to sort the list by removing the case order. Example:

"caB" => "aBc"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `string-collate-lessp` as the predicate:

```
string-collate-lessp is a built-in function in ‘src/fns.c’.

(string-collate-lessp S1 S2 &optional LOCALE IGNORE-CASE)

Return t if first arg string is less than second in collation order.
Symbols are also allowed; their print names are used instead.

This function obeys the conventions for collation order in your
locale settings.  For example, punctuation and whitespace characters
might be considered less significant for sorting:

(sort '("11" "12" "1 1" "1 2" "1.1" "1.2") 'string-collate-lessp)
  => ("11" "1 1" "1.1" "12" "1 2" "1.2")

The optional argument LOCALE, a string, overrides the setting of your
current locale identifier for collation.  The value is system
dependent; a LOCALE "en_US.UTF-8" is applicable on POSIX systems,
while it would be, e.g., "enu_USA.1252" on MS-Windows systems.

If IGNORE-CASE is non-nil, characters are converted to lower-case
before comparing them.

To emulate Unicode-compliant collation on MS-Windows systems,
bind ‘w32-collate-ignore-punctuation’ to a non-nil value, since
the codeset part of the locale cannot be "UTF-8" on MS-Windows.

If your system does not support a locale environment, this function
behaves like ‘string-lessp’.
```

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, `string<` is case-sensitive.  My suggestion in your case to obtain case-insensitive sorting would be to upcase/downcase operands of that comparator, so that it is effectively case-insensitive:

```
(setq спсВыбора (sort спсВыбора (lambda (a b) (string> (downcase a) (downcase b)))))
```

Note that that is reverse-alphabetical per your example.

Comment: Thanks ebpa. At first, I was looking for exactly that. Then thinking, if during sorting the words will contain not only alphabetic characters, most likely such a solution will no longer be suitable for containing